# how to have a virtual onscreen keyboard in qt for embedded linux?

Tags: qt, qt4

how to have a global virtual onscreen keyboard in qt for embedded linux?

Answer (score 2):

Qt implements API for input panels using [QInputContext](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputcontext.html) class. See [relevant sample](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-tools-inputpanel-example.html).

Comment: there is a dead link, and the first link is useless

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment. Yes, the sample code link has changed. I have now updated the answer. Note it is for Qt4. The same approach can still be used in Qt5/widgets with some code changes. For Qt5 check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html

Comment: Just a note on Qt Virtual Keyboard: beware that it is GPLv3 (without a commercial licence).